# Android Studio Problems JDK

Tags: android, java-8

I've installed Android Studio on Windows 10 and when I opened example project it gives error that he needs JDK1.8 and on the machine is installed JDK 1.7. I installed and uninstalled JDK1.8 twice but the message stays the same

Answer (score 1):

There is simple way to do this. Please add following lines in build.gradle in android section:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and sync project with Gradle files. Android Studio will detect change (language Level) and ask to reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Jdk Location. Change the directory of JDK location to that of your JDK 1.8 's location

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have define the address of jdk in system environment variables.
for this just follow me:
Step 1:- Open your **System Properties**.
Step 2:- Now open **Adavanced System Settings** located on upper left corner.
Step 3:- Now in **Advanced** tab open **Environment Variables**.
Step 4:- Now in **User variables for PC** add a new variable by clicking on **New** Button.
Step 5:- Now in Variable name Input **PATH** and set variable value to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin**.

Now open Android Studio.
Hope this will work for you. :-)